# Installation error in angular ui calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

i have just downloaded the files from angular ui calendar

```
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar
```

then I click demo/index.html and it shows error that some packages does not exist.
it using bower,

please do let me know how can i mwk it working in my local syatem, or please let me know the steps to work the UI calendar using bower

So far i did the following

> 1-  Manually downloaded the calendar UI calendar and its jquery version.
>
> 2-  Created a local directory and copied the index.html from angualar UI
>
> 3- included the following styles in the header  
>         -- bootstrap.css
>         -- fullcalendar.css
>
> 4-  Added the following script 
>         -- jquery.js
>         -- jquery-ui.js
>         -- angular.js
>         -- ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js
>         -- fullcalendar.js
>         -- gcal.js
>         -- calendar.js
>
> update
>
> ---

I have installed manually without using bower

so please let me know how to access the calendar object

I found the Documentation like this, but i consoled the $scope object and some function code displaying there.

```
<div ui-calendar="calendarOptions" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar">

$scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar

but i couldnt able to figure it out
```

thanks

Comment: did you all the points under [usage](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#usage)?

Comment: i have added many script to work. can you please tell how it use..?

Comment: please do let me know how to install using bower

Comment: it's really hard to guess what's going wrong without more information.  in short: install bower, add bower config file to your project, run 'bower install' in console. have a look at these docs: [bower](https://github.com/bower/bower) and [angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) a project example. not sure if this helps you :s

Comment: hi, @nilsK i fixed the bower installation from your doc.

Comment: Please let me know how i can use the calendar object in angular version.

Answer (score 2):

you will need a config object in your scope for your calendar. the following example is from the [github source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar) you posted

**controller**:

```
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        dayClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize
      }
    };
```

**template**:

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources">
```

[follow this link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) to a very good documentation. the page describes plenty of options and has some examples on how to use the calendar.